# ¿Cómo leer archivo properties que esta dentro del package JEE?

Tags: java, java-8, archivo-de-propiedades, attached-properties

Tengo una aplicación web en java 1.8, dentro de esta tengo un package llamado properties, dentro de este existe un archivo `.properties` llamado `datasorce.properties` estoy tratando de leer el archivo en una clase java para utilizar la propiedades pero no encuentra la ruta especifica.

```
 Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(new FileInputStream("src/properties/datasource.properties"));
```

intente leerlo de esta forma pero no es posible igual que las siguientes maneras

```
 Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(new FileInputStream("../src/properties/datasource.properties"));

 Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(new FileInputStream("../../src/properties/datasource.properties"));
```

[image: esta es la estructura]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La carpeta src es donde están los *sources* (código fuente), no existe dentro del fichero jar. En tiempo de ejecución puedes usar lo siguiente:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();   
prop.load(this.getClass().
    getResourceAsStream("/properties/datasource.properties"));
```

Que es la forma de buscar *recursos* de la aplicación, basándose en el *classpath*.

Comment: Lamentablemente no funciona

Comment: Me arroja un NullPointerException

Comment: Hay que crear el objeto primero, claro

Comment: he añadido en la respuesta lo que faltaba, obvié el crear una instancia de Properties

Comment: Funciono perfecto lo único es que toca agregar el / antes del nombre package

Comment: A mi me funcionó perfecto para cargar `load()` el properties, pero ahora necesito también para el método de seteo, el `config.store()`. Cómo llamaría al classpath en este método?